# How to print card by JLabel in opposite direction in GUI?

Tags: java, swing, awt, jlabel

My GUI output is picture 1. I want to print the card in the opposite direction, as in picture 2. I use JLabel to store each card as my code shown. Any .swing or .awt method can help me do this?

```
CardLabel = LabelCard(cardsInHand);
int xcoordinate = 100;
for ( JLabel Label : CardLabel){
    this.add(Label);
    Label.setBounds(i += 20 , (int) (frame.getHeight()/5.8 * game.getCurrentIdx()  +20  ) , Label.getIcon().getIconWidth(), Label.getIcon().getIconHeight() );  
}
```

Picture 1:
[image]

Picture 2:
[image]

Comment: Which picture is which? I might also suggest you invest some time to research `JLayeredPane`

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

public static BufferedImage FlippTheImage(BufferedImage bi) {
        BufferedImage flipped = new BufferedImage(bi.getWidth(), bi.getHeight(),
        bi.getType());
        AffineTransform tran = AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(0,
        bi.getHeight());
    AffineTransform flip = AffineTransform.getScaleInstance(1d, -1d);
    tran.concatenate(flip);

    Graphics2D g = flipped.createGraphics();
    g.setTransform(tran);
    g.drawImage(bi, 0, 0, null);
    g.dispose();

    return flipped;
  }
```

in this example im using AffineTransform  to flip the image you can see the doumentation for more details https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/advanced/transforming.html

you can convert your icon in jlabel to bufffered image by this approach

```
public BufferedImage getLabelTOBufferImg(){
        BufferedImage img;
        int imgW, imgH,
        Icon icon = lable.getIcon();
        imgW = icon.getIconWidth();
        imgH = icon.getIconHeight();
        img = new BufferedImage(imgW, imgH, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        return img;
    }
```